# custom toolbox in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am new to enterprise architect. I have designed an activity diagram. I wanted to know if it possible for me to add this activity diagram into a custom toolbox and use it in further projects. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards
sanjay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the MDG technology to realize a custom toolbox.

Read about [MDG](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.2/standard_uml_models/mdgtechnologies_2.html) and [how to create custom Toolboxes](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.2/standard_uml_models/custom_toolboxes.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links. I was able to create a profile, add my classes to it and view my classes in the custom toolbox.

But I am not able to include activity diagrams into the custom toolbox. Any idea about that.

Comment: Save the activity diagram as a UML Pattern. If you include the pattern in your MDG Technology, you can add it to a custom toolbox.